# Using Yun bridge library on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, arduino, bridge

I am new here and this is my first post. I am not 100% sure where to post this. I think it is something on the OS level so I chose to post it here. Moderators please move it to the correct place if it does not belong here.

I am developing a controller to control a industrial type process. I started off using the Arduino Yun that is a all in one type board with a Linux processor and Arduino controller on one board (if you dont know that already). It uses what they call the Bridge to communicate between the 2. Basically it talks over the com port and you don't have to build your own protocol, it does it for you.

Now the Yun is turning out to be to low specked for what I want to do so now I want to use a Raspberry Pi and hookup an Arduino Mega to do all the low level sensor stuff.

As luck would have it Paul Stoffregen ported the library so it can work on any linux type system using any Arduino board

(Arduino Code) https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Bridge
(Python Code for the linux side) https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/BridgeUSB

So what it does is you set-up the Pi so when you connect the Arduino it will auto login on the comm port as root (via the usb connection) and then it should start the Bridge.py script. Now here is my problem, in fact I have 2 of them

1) The Bridge.py script does not fire (it does not start up)
2) The Arduino does not auto connect on a Pi reboot.

I can see the Arduino is connecting as root when I plug it in

```
root@RedPi:~# who
root     ttyACM0      2016-03-10 18:01
```

I have the Arduino side working as I can see it is sending the data.
If I cat the port I can see it is sending the data

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0
run-bridge
▒XX100▒q▒XX100▒q▒XX100▒q▒XX100▒q▒XX100▒q▒XX100▒q▒X    ...........................
```

But it does not run or execute the "run-bridge" command. But if I type it as root on a ssh session it runs.

And then if I reboot the Pi I have to pull out the plug and push it back to connect to ttyACMo again. But when I do a lsusb I can see the Arduino there. I guess I have to add a bit of config to tell linux to do it at startup.

You have to add this bit. And I was hoping it would take care of the USB at boot as well

```
# UDEV Rules automatically start a shell on a USB Serial device.
#
# This file must be placed at:
#
# /etc/udev/rules.d/00-bridge.rules
#
KERNEL=="ttyACM*", RUN+="/usr/bin/run-bridge-udev", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1", ENV{MTP_NO_PROBE}="1"
```

I hope you can help me. I do not want to rewrite all my code that is working on the Yun. So if I can port it it will be great.